# Special character display in UI

Tags: c#, oracle

I am writing an application(C#) for a specific Character like science symbol(μo).In Oracle DB store properly.
This application involves using DataAdapter, OLEDB Connection (oracle 11g)and the DataSet. when i am displaying data in UI.
Instead of displaying the correct characters the application displays æo ("æo").
Thanks in advance

Comment: What encoding does the Oracle DB use to store that text column? Also, not all fonts support all Unicode characters (although Greek characters should be supported always).

Comment: DB:
NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16


Table Column is VARCHAR2 (50 Byte)

when i connect DB through sqlplus it shows proper char ("µo").
but in application not showing properly.

Comment: Can you simply change the column type to `nvarchar`? Or do you have an existing db? Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222529/trouble-using-displaying-special-characters-from-oracle-db-in-net-app?rq=1) also.

Comment: already did the same but no result

Comment: When you query the data in sqlplus, can you check the "NLS_LANG" setting in that environment? On UNIX this will simply be an environment variable, on DOS a mixture of Environment Variable/Registry setting. In simple terms NLS_LANG controls how the data served up by the query is displayed/represented on the screen/in the app. See this answer to help understand how this affects displays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584283/when-insert-persian-character-in-oracle-db-i-see-the-question-mark/24597374#24597374 .

Comment: I am query the data in sqlplus, able to see proper symbol(μo).when i fetch data  & fill in data table, that time it convert to æo.