# Reading ñ from Oracle using Powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I have an oracle view that I'm reading data from in order to synchronise Active Directory information, I have a lookup function that cleanses special characters before updating active directory.  All of this works great until the letter ñ appears in Oracle.

When I import the data it shows the ñ as ?

Here's the code I'm using

```
# Load the ODBC assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient")

# attempt to connect to the oracle database, if it fails exit the script with an error in the logfile, otherwise go and get the users in the network request view.
try{
  $oraConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection 
  $oraConn.ConnectionString = $variableObject.compConStr
  $oraConn.Open()
}catch [Exception]{
  $_.Exception | Format-List -Force | Out-File C:\corpit\exceptionTrace.txt -Force
}finally{
  # attempt to retrieve users from the network request view, if it fails throw an error and exit the script
  # otherwise create an object for each record in the table and add it to the users array
  try{

    $sql = "select * from table.view"

    $command = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($sql,$oraConn)

    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
  }catch [Exception]{

  }finally{
    # read the query and for each record create an object to add to the users array 
    while ($reader.read()) {

      If($reader.IsDBNull(1) -or $reader.IsDBNull(2) ){
      }Else{
        $uniqueID = $reader.GetValue(0)  
        $giveName = $reader.GetValue(1)
        $familyName = $reader.GetValue(2)
        $oracleId = $reader.GetValue(3)
        $location = $reader.GetValue(4)
        $personalEmail = $reader.GetValue(5)
        $managerEmail = $reader.GetValue(6)
        Switch($reader.GetValue(7)){ 
          "*No*" {$atCompany = $false} 
          default {$atCompany = $true} 
        }
        $businessUnit = $reader.GetValue(8) 
        $costCenter = $reader.GetValue(9)
        $employeeType = $reader.GetValue(10)
        $remoteworker = $reader.GetValue(11)
        $ContractExpiration = $reader.GetValue(12)
        $JobTitle = $reader.GetValue(13)

        $importObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
          "Unique_ID"          = $uniqueID
          "FirstName"          = Replace-SpecialCharacter $giveName.Trim()
          "LastName"           = Replace-SpecialCharacter $familyName.Trim()
          "Location"           = $location
          "PersonalEmail"      = $personalEmail
          "ManagerEmail"       = $managerEmail
          "atCompany"          = $atCompany
          "oracleId"           = $oracleId
          "businessUnit"       = $businessUnit
          "costCenter"         = $costCenter
          "employeeType"       = $employeeType
          "remoteWorker"       = $remoteworker
          "ContractExpiration" = $ContractExpiration
          "JobTitle"           = $JobTitle
        } 

        $usersToUpdate += $importObj
      }
    }

    If ($oraConn.State -eq 'Open') { $oraConn.close() }
  }
}
```

I've tried re-encoding the received data in UTF8 and Unicode but it seems that its already returning ? before it can get to that stage.

This is the code I used to try and re-encode the string

```
$textObject = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$oracleString = $textObject.GetBytes($reader.GetValue(2))
$familyName = $textObject.GetString($oracleString)
```

I've tried using GetString as well and that returns the same result.

Comment: It looks like you're using the Odbc client, but [System.Data.OracleClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient(v=vs.100).aspx) is obsolete.  You should be using Oracle's [Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).  You might also want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222529/trouble-using-displaying-special-characters-from-oracle-db-in-net-app).

Comment: I'm using ODBC because of different issues that arose with ODP.NET, basically it wouldn't run via task scheduler when the account running it wasn't logged into the server.  But it does seem that might be the issue with the conversion, if it's as simple as that I'll just have to get the DB team to do the conversion for me at the database level.

Comment: What is you `NLS_LANG` Environment variable, resp. your Registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG`? I assume the charset does not support UTF-8.

Comment: Why do you load `System.Data.OracleClient` when you use `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection` afterwards? I don't think this is needed. What is your ConnectionString?